# Why SSH is asking for my private key password each time

Tags: ssh, password

Since yesterday, each time I try to connect to an ssh server, I got asked for my password. What should I do to make SSH not ask for my password each time.

Comment: Blind guess by me: check that your key is loaded with `ssh-add -l`.

Comment: I assume you are using ssh keys? If you don't use a keymanager and have a non-empty passphrase, this is normal. Either use a keymanager or create an empty passphrase for your key. I guess the former is recommended.

Comment: if it's "since yesterday", maybe it's just that you have updated your system, and now ssh-agent does not work anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your public key in `hostmachine:~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and make sure it has the appropriate permissions (use `chmod 600`). See the man page, section AUTHENTICATION, for more details. Note that sshd maybe configured to disallow this method of login although I cannot fathom why.

Comment: Thank, that worked. However could you explain me why do I have to put it in authorized_keys and why it was working without it before.

Comment: The man page has the information in the AUTHENTICATION section.  As to why it was working before hand, I cannot be sure without having root access to your machines and doing some forensics work.

Comment: You can also use **ssh-copy-id** in order to get your public key automatically copied to destination host, if you don't want/need to copy it manually.

Answer (score 2):

Check directory permissions, and file permissions.

`$HOME` can't be writeable by group or other.

`$HOME/.ssh` needs to have `700` permissions, not readable, writeable or executable by group and other.

`$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` to be not writeable or executable by anyone.

If you find that permissions aren't strict enough, try to figure out what caused the problem. Last time this happened to me, I had compiled PHP from scratch.  Executing `make install` as root (Slackware) changed the permissions and ownership of `/` or `/home` as I recall, and kept ssh from working with `authorized_keys` and `id_rsa.pub` files that had been in place and working for ages. You want to determine what caused the problem, as changed directory ownership and/or permission can happen because of a rootkit install or something like that.

Comment: This fixed it for me.. After fixing my permissions, I added it using 'ssh-add'.. after closing that terminal and re-opening it and doing 'ssh-add -l' (lower L) I could see my identity, which worked.. I could SSH to all my boxes without having to type my private key pass 300+ times a day!! Thank you!